# Would have +past participle/or will

Tags: tense, irrealis-mood

> We'd better buy something useful with the money would have spent or /will spend for the wedding party.

My question is for you as a native speaker which one you might use and why?

Answer (score 1):

If you're not going to have the wedding party, you would say "would have spent." If you talk about the money you "will spend" on the wedding party, that means you're planning to have the party and to spend that money on it.